# url hyperref does not work with French accent characters

Tags: hyperref, urls, accents

I am using `pdflatex`.

The following creates a live link the the first URL ("mousse" with no French accent). When I click on it in the PDF, I am brought to that page. The second URL (containing two acute French accents) looks right in the PDF but the link is dead.

When I use `latex` and `dvipdfm`, two live links are created but they do not bring me to the proper place.

How can I get live URLs in my PDF, when the URLs contain European accented characters?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

This creates a live link in the PDF:

\url{http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/mousse/52833}

The following looks all right in the PDF but is a dead link:

\url{http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/écrémer/27576?q=écrémé}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The start of my log file says: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011/Fink)

Answer (score 6):

The URL should be percent encoded:

```
\href{http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/%C3%A9cr%C3%A9mer/27576?q=%C3%A9cr%C3%A9m%C3%A9}{%
  \nolinkurl{http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais-anglais/écrémer/27576?q=écrémé}}
```

Copying and pasting the URL from the location bar of the browser (firefox, ...) usually gets the percent encoded version of the URL.

Comment: Copying the URL from Firefox 23.0.1 on a Mac 10.6.8 got the percent-encoded URL.  

Copying the URL from Safari 10.6.8 on the same Mac **did not get** the percent encoding.

This answered my question.

Comment: @JacobWegelin Since you this answers your question, please consider marking it as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below the vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `\url{}` and escape the percentage symbols with a backslash. Maybe not as clean as the other answer but I couldn't make it work as explained so I used this approach and it worked.

As an example, for the url http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_satisfacci%C3%B3n_de_restricciones, the code would be this:

```
\url{http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_de_satisfacci\%C3\%B3n_de_restricciones}
```

Comment: Why would you escape the percentage symbols? The result would print *with* the backslashes, which doesn't yield the correct web address anymore.

Comment: @Werner: It's a feature of `hyperref`. Otherwise it would be a little difficult to specify the percent character (comment character in TeX) in URLs, if `\url` or `\href` are used inside `\footnote{...}` or other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I spent too much time figuring this out I will post this as an answer. I needed to **combine** the ideas in the two answers above.

The source code snippet

```
\begin{center}
\href{https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr\%C3\%A9_Weil}
{\nolinkurl{https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/André_Weil}}
\end{center}
```

produced a link in the pdf-document that actually points at [the desired url](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Weil) as well as prints the url as it is seen in the browser rather than in unicode.

So

- use the `\href{...}{\nolinkurl{...}}` construct from Heiko's answer, and
- remember to escape the `%` characters in the copy/pasted url as explained by aldr0.