# Using url package without hyperref makes link hit boxes erratic

Tags: urls

I've currently got a url link in a footnote in my document. With the `hyperref` package, everything works correctly. Because the IEEE PDF Express tool doesn't like having the `hyperref` package, I've removed it and only left in the `url` package.

However, some strange behavior occurs as a result of this. Instead of just the link being clickable, entire paragraphs of text before/after end up being clickable and going to the same link. This occurs for both Skim and Preview in Mac OSX.

Does anyone have an inkling of what might be causing this?

Comment: Without `hyperref` no hyperlink is created by LaTeX; however, PDF previewers on Mac OS X have heuristics that try finding URL's (or, more generally, URI's) in the PDF files. Such heuristics usually fail. `:-(`

Comment: Could you provide an MWE?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: It does appear that by using Adobe Reader, this issue does not turn up at all. Perhaps it is indeed a failure on the part of Mac OS X pdf readers whenever a pdf file doesn't use the hyperref package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without `hyperref` no hyperlink is created by LaTeX; however, PDF previewers on Mac OS X have heuristics that try finding URL's (or, more generally, URI's) in the PDF files.

Such heuristics often try being too smart and fail. :-(

So it's not a LaTeX problem, but of the Apple library PDF viewers are based on (Preview, Skim and others). Since Adobe Reader is not based on that Apple library, the link are indeed not recognized.

Comment: This seems not to be Mac OS X specific; also PDF viewers on other operating systems can show the problem.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen With `hyperref` it should be possible.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do you mean [Heiko's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132700/4427)?