# XeLaTeX href fails if accents in the link

Tags: beamer, xetex, accents, emacs, href

This piece of code should create a document with a link to  [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_mémoire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_m%C3%A9moire)

Instead of that the link goes to [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_mÃ©moire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_m%C3%83%C2%A9moire)

Why is that? How to solve the problem?

Edited : The percent encoding gives a working link but `indent-region` in emacs (on OS X) gives now false indentation and the log file is showing a problem.

```
% Pour XeTeX
\XeTeXdefaultencoding utf-8

\documentclass[10pt,svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes} % gestion des guillemets (pas sûr que cela reste indispensable avec polyglossia)
\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Pour des raisons d'\href{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_mémoire}{alignement
      en mémoire}, le format BMP a recours au padding.

  \item Pour des raisons d'\href{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_m%C3%A9moire}{alignement en mémoire}, le format BMP a recours au padding.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The beginning and the end of the log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.2.18)  19 JUN 2020 09:32
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2019/09/29 v3.57 A class for typesetting presentations
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasemodes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count163
)
\beamer@tempbox=\box45
\beamer@tempcount=\count164
\c@beamerpauses=\count165

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbasedecode.sty
\beamer@slideinframe=\count166
\beamer@minimum=\count167
\beamer@decode@box=\box46
)
\beamer@commentbox=\box47
\beamer@modecount=\count168
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests
))

---------------------------------------------------   

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-basic-dicti
onary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-basic-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-bibliograph
y-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-bibliography-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-environment
-dictionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-environment-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-months-dict
ionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-months-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-numbers-dic
tionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-numbers-dictionary, Language: English 
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translator/translator-theorem-dic
tionary-English.dict
Dictionary: translator-theorem-dictionary, Language: English 
)

Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid
(fontspec)             this).

\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup8
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `TU' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/b/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathrm on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/m/it --> TU/lmr/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/b/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/m/n --> TU/lmss/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  TU/lmtt/m/n --> TU/lmtt/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmr/m/n --> TU/lmr/b/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/b/it --> TU/lmr/b/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmss/b/n --> TU/lmss/b/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  TU/lmtt/b/n --> TU/lmtt/b/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 12.
 (./test.nav))
Runaway argument?
\begin {itemize} \item Pour des raisons d'\href {https://fr.wikipedia\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frame.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex
            
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> test.tex
            
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 24768 strings out of 479819
 500728 string characters out of 5893613
 811726 words of memory out of 5000000
 41412 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532730 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 58i,4n,67p,792b,289s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Comment: works fine for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132700. Short answer: use percent encoding `\href{https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Alignement_en_m%C3%A9moire}{...}`.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with xelatex/lualatex and pdf reader Skim or TeXstudio's internal pdf viewer on macOS, but Adobe Reader works ok. I also checked the url stored in pdf, it is `{'/S': '/URI', '/URI': 'https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Alignement_en_mÃ©moire'}`. So the stored url is probably wrong.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in xelatex on Windows:
All of `Acrobat Reader DC`, `SumatraPDF`, `TeXstudio`, `TeXworks`
show correct accent in the link.

Comment: I can find the correct
`/A<</S/URI/URI(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_mémoire)>>`
in both of xdv and pdf.

Comment: @muzimuzhi you led me to the solution so thank you

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I get the correct `URI(https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_m\303\251moire)`. Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I add an answer to post what I get.

Comment: You get the error from the percent encoding as \href can't change the catcode in a beamer frame. You should use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer `\begin{frame}[fragile]` doesn't solve the indentation problem with `indent-region` in emacs. Also what's follow the first percent is considered as a comment. So I need to add the backslashs.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some bug in macOS.

```
% url-test.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Alignement_en_mémoire}{alignement en mémoire}
\end{document}
```

Run the above example with

```
xelatex -no-pdf url-test.tex
dviasm url-test.xdv > url-test.dviasm
xdvipdfmx -C 0x40 url-test.xdv
```

then

- the `.dviasm` file contains `URI(https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Alignement_en_mémoire)`, and
- the `.pdf` file contains `URI(https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Alignement_en_m\303\251moire)`.

Both are right.

If I click the url in TeXstudio's internal pdf viewer or Skim.app, then both of them open `https://www.wikiwand.com/fr/Alignement_en_m%EF%BF%BDmoire`, which is wrong. Adobe Reader opens the right url, however.

I am on macOS 10.15.5, with texlive 2020 and latest latex packages.

Comment: yes, that is quite probable. There are known problems with mac os handling of certain links.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And I can remember [this issue](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/110), which shows macOS (probably the PDFKit module) wrongly converts the reserved character `#` to percent encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The percent coding solve the problem without additional errors if we escape the percentage symbols with a backslash.

```
% Pour XeTeX
\XeTeXdefaultencoding utf-8

\documentclass[10pt,svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{csquotes} % gestion des guillemets (pas sûr que cela reste indispensable avec polyglossia)
\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Pour des raisons d'\href{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_mémoire}{alignement
      en mémoire}, le format BMP a recours au padding.

  \item Pour des raisons d'\href{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alignement_en_m\%C3\%A9moire}{alignement en mémoire}, le format BMP a recours au padding.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So the procedure is to copy the address from firefox to get the percent encoding and then add backslashs.

Comment: Percent encoding is certainly one way to resolve it. But it should also work without it. Can you show your log-file?

Comment: I tested by XeTeX 0.999992 (TeX Live 2020).
Raoul HATTERER is using XeTeX 0.999991 (TeX Live 2019).
I don't know but there may be differences in the engine
or/and packages.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto I tried on texlive 2019 and it worked fine too. Imho muzimuzhi is right and it is a mac os problem, its pdf viewer is faulty in various places.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto not related to this question, but if you have some time, could you look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550325/2388?