# LuaLaTeX does not compile after upgrade to TeX Live 2020

Tags: luatex, texlive

Edit: Compiling documents by running LuaLaTeX as an administrator does work. Therefore, running my editor (TeXstudio) as an administrator does serve as a workaround. However the question remains, why this is suddenly necessary after upgrading to TeX Live 2020.

After upgrading from TeX Live 2019 to TeX Live 2020, I am no more able to compile documents with LuaLaTeX. PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX work fine.

Even compiling a minimal document leads to no result, here is the example and the log:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)  (format=lualatex 2020.6.20)  20 JUN 2020 19:28
restricted system commands enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
Lua module: luaotfload-main 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload entry point
Lua module: luaotfload-init 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / initializatio
n
Lua module: lualibs 2020-05-01 2.71 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-05-01 2.71 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
Lua module: luaotfload-log 2020-05-06 3.14 luaotfload submodule / logging
```

This problem appears on both of my machines, running Windows 10.
So far, I have tried to update my packages using Tex Live Manager and a reinstall of Tex Live 2020.

Running `luaotfload-tool -u -vvv` yields:

```
luaotfload | util : Task completed successfully.
luaotfload | db : Updating the font names database.
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from C:/texlive/2020/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic-dev/names/luaotfload-names.luc
luaotfload | db : Loading took 20 ms.
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgbd.ttf" via "c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgbi.ttf" via "c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgit.ttf" via "c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisted file "spltfgrg.ttf" via "c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-blacklist.cnf".
luaotfload | db : Blacklisting 4 files and directories.
luaotfload | db : Whitelisting 0 files.
luaotfload | db : Scanning TEXMF and $OSFONTDIR for fonts...
luaotfload | db : Path "." matches $PWD ("c:/windows/system32"), skipping.
luaotfload | db : Path "." matches $PWD ("c:/windows/system32"), skipping.
luaotfload | db : Path "." matches $PWD ("c:/windows/system32"), skipping.
luaotfload | db : Path "." matches $PWD ("c:/windows/system32"), skipping.
luaotfload | db : Initiating scan of 954 directories.
luaotfload | db : Collected 5768 files.
luaotfload | db : Scanning system fonts...
luaotfload | db : Searching in static system directories...
luaotfload | db : Collected 387 files.
luaotfload | db : Scanning 6155 collected font files ...
luaotfload | db : Found 6155 font files; 0 new, 0 stale entries.
luaotfload | db : Creating filename map.
luaotfload | db : Analyzing families.
luaotfload | db : Analyzing shapes, weights, and styles.
luaotfload | db : Ordering design sizes.
luaotfload | db : Rebuilt in 11602 ms.
luaotfload | db : No new or removed fonts, skip saving to disk.
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache saved.
luaotfload | cache : Lookup cache emptied.
luaotfload | db : Fonts in the database: 2535
luaotfload | util : Task completed successfully.
```

Comment: does the log really stop there? Can you compile on a terminal and look if you get some lua error?

Comment: Yes it stops there. Compiling on a terminal (PowerShell) shows no error

Comment: Hm. Well it works fine for me, and I'm windows 10 too. Is anything unusual in your setup? For example installation path, user name, ...?

Comment: The installation path is in C:\texlive\2020 (as was C:\texlive\2019 ), my username contains a "ü", if that might be a problem.

Comment: can you run a small plain tex file e.g. `abc \bye` with `luahbtex file` on a terminal?

Comment: Done – this works fine.

Comment: what happens if you run `luaotfload-tool -u`? (in case it fails you could add -vvv to get more messages.)

Comment: I'm not sure how to run ```luaotfload-tool -u```. In a terminal? In this case, nothing happens.

Comment: what happens is you add `-vvv`? (this should make the message more verbose)

Comment: Still nothing, nothing happens in any case.

Comment: hm. does `luaotfload-tool --help` say something?

Comment: ```luaotfload-tool --help``` has no effect as well.

Comment: do you have a luaotfload-tool.exe in texlive/2020/bin/win32?

Comment: Yes, luaotfload-tool.exe is at this location.

Comment: and a luaotfload-tool.lua in scripts/luaotfload? Does it look ok? (You can open it in your editor, it is a textfile)

Comment: File exist and look ok, as far as I can tell (1660 lines).

Comment: However I managed to get a result from ```luaotfload-tool -u -vvv``` by running the terminal as an administrator (...). I will edit the result in the post above.

Comment: Compiling documents with LuaLaTeX as an administrator does work. See the edit above.

Comment: well the question is if is a problem of access rights or a problem with the ü in the user name.

Comment: Yes, however, I do not understand why this would only affect LuaLatex in Tex Live 2020. I guess I will have to do some experiments. For now, I am happy that I can compile my files again. Thank you for the support!

Comment: There have been some changes regarding the handling of non-ascii chars. This is quite recent. But I don't quite see why it should affect a call `luaotfload-tool --help`.

Comment: Could you look for `luaotfload-database.lua` (somewhere in `\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\tex\luatex\luaotfload`), open it in your editor. Line 2417 should start with `return { filejoin(windir, 'Fonts')`. Could you comment this line by adding two hyphen `--`. Then save the file and try again?

Comment: This yields the same results as before, lualatex does not compile.

Comment: This doesn't sound as if the ü in the user name is the source of your problems. For good measure you could also comment the two lines before (`local appdata` 
 and `local windir`). Imho this are the only one which actually could be affected by the user name.

Comment: I commented the mentioned two lines as well, the result does not change.

Comment: hm. And what happens if you open a command line (or powershell) in texmf-dist/scripts/luaotfload and run `texlua.exe .\luaotfload-tool.lua --help`?

Comment: Nothing unless I run the cmd or PowerShell as an admin -- then it works fine.

Comment: can you run lua scripts at all? I mean if you write `print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")` in some test.lua and then run texlua.exe .\test.lua does it work?

Comment: Yes, the x's are printed in the terminal.

Comment: well I can't reproduce it, and so can't investigate the lua and without any error message it is difficult to guess. You could try some of the other command line options (e.g. --diagnose=permissions or --diagnose=environment, or --version).  Or copy the lua in some test folder, and then start to investigate. E.g. by adding print commands in various place. The main function is at the end of the file.