# How can I have automatic line-breaking for URL containing Unicode characters?

Tags: hyperref, unicode, urls, xurl

Some URLs include unicode characters. For example `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson_statistics`. All (most?) webbrowsers are able to handle such URLs but some PDF viewers (like Mac's Preview and Skim) aren't. How would one show such a URL in a LaTeX document?

You can obviously use `\href{encoded URL}{original URL}` but this one fails to linebreak the "original URL" part.

The plain `\url{original URL}` command does print the correct URL but this hyperlink doesn't work because it contains unicode characters.

Using the encoded URL `\url{encoded URL}` does work and it linebreaks but it's too ugly to print.

I think it would be nice if the `\url` command encoded the URL for the hyperlink without altering the text it prints.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\noindent%
1. blah blah blah blah blah blah\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin\%E2\%80\%93Watson_statistic}%
{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson\_statistic}

\noindent%
2. blah blah blah blah blah blah\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin\%E2\%80\%93Watson_statistic}

\noindent%
3. blah blah blah blah blah blah\url{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson\_statistic}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Thank you for the solution below, where `\nolinkurl` solves the problem even with pdflatex, but this discussion has made me realize that pdflatex is not quite able to handle unicode gracefully. If you copy the URL text from the generated PDF, the text in the clipboard is not always "correct":

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr\%C3\%B6dinger}%
{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin\_Schr}ö\nolinkurl{dinger}}
\end{document}
```

pdflatex this document, open it with a PDF viewer, copy the text of the URL, and paste it into the address box of a webbrowser. The character *ö* is copied as * ̈o* and this URL doesn't work.

Unfortunately, this isn't a contrived complaint because you sometimes want to copy the URL instead of clicking on it. (Sometimes you just don't want to click on it.)

lualatex produces *ö* in the PDF. This problem isn't directly relevant to my original problem. I should've used lualatex in the first place.

Comment: I have edited my answer to reply to you edit. Hope this helps.

Comment: Related question: [pdftex - Hyperref: Scandinavian characters (æø) don't work in \url, hyperlink is wrong - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/hyperref-scandinavian-characters-%C3%A6%C3%B8-dont-work-in-url-hyperlink-is-wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest is to use lualatex, where it works more or less out-of-the-box (or at least it is solvable by defining a suitable font):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\noindent%
1. blah blah blah blah blah blah\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin\%E2\%80\%93Watson_statistic}%
{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson_statistic}}

\end{document}
```

When using the new PDF management by starting with `\DocumentMetadata` you can even let the code do the percent encoding for you:

```
\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\noindent%
1. blah blah blah blah blah blah\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin\%E2\%80\%93Watson_statistic}%
{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson_statistic}}

\url[urlencode]{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson_statistic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With pdflatex there is no good solution. The way the url package works (by switching to math) makes it up-to impossible to properly support unicode. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/670811/2388. So you will have to insert break points manually in such cases.

Comment: Thanks! But, I was surprised that with the `luacolor` package and with the `colorlink=true` option of the `hyperref` package, `\DocumentMetadata{}` renders the links in blank!  (I meant to ask why `DocumentMetadata` isn't set by default, but I guess that's because there is some unwanted interaction like this?)

Comment: The pdfmanagement code is quite stable, but there are packages which aren't compatible with, see the documentation of pdfmanagement-testphase. If you find some unwanted interaction please report it at  https://github.com/latex3/pdfresources. (color problems are quite possible, with the new code: hyperref uses l3color, but that isn't fully integrated with xcolor and luacolor and unifying everything isn't trivial but if I get a report I will try to resolve it.)

Comment: With `\nolinkurl`, there is a solution with pdflatex (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution (I add `\urlstyle{rm}` because when `\nolinkurl` is used, by default, the URL is displayed in typewriter font):

1 is your first attempt.

2 is almost the solution, but the en dash isn't displayed.

3 is the solution.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{rm}
\usepackage[breaklinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\noindent%
1. blah blah blah blah blah blah\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin\%E2\%80\%93Watson_statistic}%
{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson\_statistic}

\noindent%
2. blah blah blah blah blah blah\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin\%E2\%80\%93Watson_statistic}%
{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin–Watson\_statistic}}

\noindent%
3. blah blah blah blah blah blah\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin\%E2\%80\%93Watson_statistic}%
{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbi}--\nolinkurl{Watson\_statistic}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

In answer to the edited question:

Replace:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr\%C3\%B6dinger}%
{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin\_Schr}ö\nolinkurl{dinger}}
\end{document}
```

with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Necessary for using things like `\"o` in `\nolinkurl`
\usepackage{url} % For the style of the displayed URL
\urlstyle{rm} % For using the roman style (in place of typewriter)

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr\%C3\%B6dinger}%
{\nolinkurl{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin\_Schr\"odinger}} % replacing ö by \"o, you can put everything in \nolinkurl
\end{document}
```

By adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and replacing ö by `\"o`, you can put everything in `\nolinkurl`.

(`\usepackage{url}` and `\urlstyle{rm}` is optional, you can avoid it if you like typewriter style).

You obtain then:

[image]

and if you copy it in the PDF reader, you will obtain `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erwin_Schrödinger` as expected.